# Splitting one field from model into two form input fields on django update view

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have this `customer model` with only one address field.

```
class PullingCustomer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Code', max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Customer', max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name='Address', max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name='City', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    cust = "{0.name}"
    return cust.format(self)
```

but on my `form.py`, I split it into two input, address 1 and address 2.

```
class PullingCustomerForm(ModelForm):
    address1 = forms.CharField(max_length=155)
    address2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PullingCustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            ....
            Row(
                Column('address1', css_class = 'col-md-12'),
                css_class = 'row'
                ),
            Row(
                Column('address2', css_class = 'col-md-8'),
                Column('city', css_class = 'col-md-4'),
                css_class = 'row'
                ),
            ....
    class Meta:
        model = PullingCustomer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then I combine them again on `view.py` so I can save it.

```
class PullingCustomerCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PullingCustomerForm
    template_name = 'pulling_customer_input.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        address1 = form.cleaned_data['address1']
        address2 = form.cleaned_data['address2']
        temp_form = super(PullingCustomerCreateView, self).form_valid(form = form)
        form.instance.address = str(address1) + ', ' + str(address2)
        form.save()
        return temp_form
```

Since I want to use the same form layout on my `update view`, I need to split the address into two again. What is the best method to do that?

```
class PullingCustomerUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = PullingCustomer
    form_class = PullingCustomerForm
    template_name = 'pulling_customer_update.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for may be covered by [MultiWidget.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget) I haven't ever written one, so I won't attempt to expand on this.

Alternatively, don't use the `address` field in a ModelForm (UpdateView). Use `fields=` to exclude `address` and add `address1` and `address2` to the form. You'll combine them in `form_valid` much as in your CreateView

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        address1 = form.cleaned_data['address1']
        address2 = form.cleaned_data['address2']
        obj = form.save( commit=False)
        obj.address = str(address1) + ', ' + str(address2)
        obj.save()
```

You'll also need some code to get the current address and use it to supply initial values for the form's `address1` and `address2`. Using UpdateView, you would subclass `get_initial`. I think:

```
def get_initial( self)
    initial = super().get_initial()
    address = self.object.address
    # split address1, address2 from address in whatever way is appropriate
    # for example, if you store with a newline \n separating them
    address1, address2 = address.split('\n', maxsplit=1) 
    initial['address1'] = address1
    initial['address2'] = address2
    return initial
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to include `get_initial` subclass and it works perfectly. 

For the time being, I implement ajax to get the address and show it on the form when the document is loaded, but I feel it's not a good practice.

On the UpdateView, I also excluded `address` field just like your suggestion, but I didn't see any differences. Perhaps because I'm reusing the same form class from CreateView for my UpdateView.

I took a glance MultiWidget and I found it suits this kind of problem, I will look into it for future reference.